# Correct way of measuring UI-Performance in WPF .Net

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, render, frame-rate

I have a method of measuring FPS in WPF (which I dont really know if it is the correct way of measuring).

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarger_Rendering;

void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var args = (RenderingEventArgs)e;
    if(args.RenderingTime == m_Last)
    {
        return;
    }
    m_Last = args.RenderingTime;

    DoingFpsCalculations(); // This method adds to a counter and reports each elapsed second what the counter is => FPS
}
```

These calculations shows me that I have approximately 40-60 FPS

However, sometimes I can visually see that this is really not the case. The FPS-counter reports lets say 50FPS but the UI is absolutely updating in lower FPS.

I Have for instance a DispatcherTimer running in 15Hz the timer calls a render method and updates transforms for ui-elements binded to their RenderTransform. The timer gets called with 15Hz and completes its calculations in time. The FPS shows me 40-60 fps but the UI-elements are absolutely updating in only 4-6 FPS for instance.

What can I rely on?

I know there is a difference between the UI-thread and the Rendering-thread so the real FPS should be measure on the Rendering-thread? But how do I get a hold of that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Years late, but for posterity I thought I'd share.  WPF will drop the amount `CompositionTarget_Rendering` is called when other events aren't going on.  One (hacky) way to get around this is to run a constant animation on the screen.  I've used a 1x1 rectangle with a double animation on repeat (it has to be somewhere on the visible surface, if you put it off the screen WPF is smart enough to ignore it).  This has the effect of keeping the composition target running at a minimum of 59-60fps on every workstation I've tested on (in your example you've already taken into account the other issue which is the fact it can run more than 60fps).